# magento paypal get error :We're sorry, PayPal doesn't allow residents of United States to ship purchases to United Kingdom

Tags: php, unit-testing, magento, paypal

while doing checkout using paypal as payment gateway i get below error:

**We're sorry, PayPal doesn't allow residents of United States to ship purchases to United Kingdom.**

how to get rid of problem i saw most of previous answer most of them are saying to change code some where in magento like address override to 1 , i want to know why how to solve this without any code changes.
please guide.

where can i do changes in setting in paypal or magento admin but not in code

Comment: are you using sandbox credential or live credential??

Comment: This is not a coding issue.This is related to your Paypal accounts.You need to make sure that Sandbox account is from country thats allowed.As per paypal terms a US customer is not allowed to purchase from UK where shipping is from UK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do one thing login into your sandbox account click on application and then sandbox account now click on create account use country united kindom and fill money and other details now you can make testing payment in your magento store